# Why isn't ICustomMarshaler being called for event delegate?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, com-interop

I'm struggling with ICustomMarshaler, and I can't find anyone else who is having this problem. The fact that I've been looking for an answer for days, and I'm finally posting here means that I'll probably find the answer ten minutes from now myself. :-\

I have a C# event being proxied to a COM event sink. I want to marshal an array of objects with two strings and an int using an ICustomMarshaler.

My problem is that I have everything defined, but my ICustomMarshaler isn't being used. I put breakpoints on GetInstance and MarshalManagedToNative, and they're never hit.

My ICustomMarshaler **does** get called when I go the other direction.

Is there a problem with using a custom marshaler with C# events/COM event sinks?

Here is the object I'm trying to serialize:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComDll
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    [Guid(ClassId), ComVisible(true)]
    public class ParamStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string Key;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string Value;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int Number;

        internal const string ClassId = "8163B82F-E0AD-47BC-8F82-EFA324DCFB95";
    }
}
```

In the object, I tried leaving off the MarshalAs attributes, since they won't actually be used, and that results in 0x80028019 (old format or invalid type library). It wouldn't if my custom marshaler were being used.

Here is my ICustomMarshaler. Note: I'm leaving out the actual function contents since GetInstance or anything else isn't being called:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComDll
{
    public class ParamStructArrayMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
    {
        private static ICustomMarshaler _marshaler;
        public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie)
        {
            if(null == _marshaler)
            {
                _marshaler = new ParamStructArrayMarshaler();
            }
            return _marshaler;
        }

        public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
        {
            // <Snip>
        }

        public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
        {
            // <Snip>
        }

        public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
        {
            // <Snip>
        }

        public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
        {
            // <Snip>
        }

        public int GetNativeDataSize()
        {
            // <Snip>
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the function definition in my interface:

```
[DispId(2)]
void ParamsWereSent(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(ParamStructArrayMarshaler)), In]
    ParamStruct[] paramArray,
    [In] int count);
```

Here's the delegate I use and the event that exposes it:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public delegate void ParamsWereSentHandler(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(ParamStructArrayMarshaler)), In]
    ParamStruct[] paramArray,
    [In] int count);
public event ParamsWereSentHandler ParamsWereSent;
```

The fact that I can't find anyone else who is having trouble actually getting their ICustomMarshaler to be called means that I'm just missing something silly.

Comment: CustomMarshaler attribute only supports reference type, not value type (class not struct). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_UnmanagedType_CustomMarshaler

Comment: You got my hopes up! I changed ParamStruct to be a class instead of a struct, and my marshaler still isn't used. I tried removing the attributes from ParamStruct, and that doesn't help, either.

Comment: Okay, another data-point. The trouble I'm having is in the event handler, which on the C++ side is a COM event sink. I just tried exposing the same thing but from C++, and the custom marshaler gets used. So is there a problem with using a custom marshaler with C# events/COM event sinks?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly... would you have a reproducing project? (also you can remove [ComVisible(false)] on delegate and  [Guid(ClassId), ComVisible(true)] attributes on ParamStruct)

Comment: I prefer to keep ComVisible(false) on the delegate. No need to clutter the registry with that, and that's not why marshaling isn't working. Here's the project. It's incomplete. It's just to work out this issue. https://github.com/jamiehankins/COMIntegration

Comment: I edited the question now that I know that it's only on event/event sink that it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use C structs like this with IDispatch interfaces. IDispatch is limited to automation types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/7b5fa59b-d8f6-4a47-9695-630d3c10363e what you can do though is wrap structs using VT_RECORD types (not super easy, but should work...).

Answer (score 0):

You are using event, which is MulticastDelegate. And as per Microsoft recommendation we multicast delegate will not work with interop.